# How can I send a parameter to a compare function in PHP?

Tags: php, class, compare, yii

To begin, I'm working entirely in PHP using the Yii framework, although Yii ultimately has little to do with this question.

I've got a class, and inside of it I have an array called $data.  I want to filter out certain elements of the array that don't match up with the parameters I'm sending to the class (I'll put some syntax below to give you a better idea).  I am therefore using array_filter, and it requires one of its inputs to be a comparison function (ie. one that returns true or false for a specific element.  Any that cause a 'false' to be returned are removed from the array).

The problem is that because the function entered is entered in quotes, I don't see a way to have the comparison function within the actual class.  But when the function is outside of the class, I can't call the instance variable that I need.  So what I really need is to be able to call the instance variable *outside* of the class somehow, to send the instance variable to the function as a parameter, or to somehow keep the comparison function within the class.

Any ideas on this?  The class I mentioned is a widget in Yii.  Below is the call to that widget (not that important).  The relevant parameter is 'params'.

```
$this->widget('application.widgets.CListViewParam', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'itemView'=>'_view',
    'params'=>array('receiverId'=>Yii::app()->user->userId),
));
```

There is an instance variable within a class in the widget to save the parameter:

```
public $params = array();
```

Then there is a call to array_filter and the comparison function:

```
$data = array_filter($data, "filterData");
```

The actual comparison function is not important, but below is the skeleton.  Remember that it is outside of the class.

```
function filterData($item) {
    // unable to access $this->params inside of this function!
}
```

Comment: Have you considered a `static` method in your class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's outside the class and can't access `$this->params`, then why not just put it inside the class:

```
class MyClass {

    public $params;

    public function widget() {
        // ...
        $filtered = array_filter($array, array($this, 'filterData'));
    }

    private function filterData($item) {
       // $this->params is now accessible
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know I could provide an array as a parameter in that way.  Easy peasy!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a lambda construct to use any variables you need in a callback. For instance, instead of hardcoding the value `1.5` in this code:

```
$array = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

function cmp($x) { return $x > 1.5; }
print_r(array_filter($array, cmp));
```

You can pass it as a variable to a lambda construct:

```
$array = Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);

$data = 1.5;
$lambda = function($x) use ($data) { return $x > $data; };
print_r(array_filter($array, $lambda));
```

If you wish to modify `$data`, use `use(&$data)`.

Comment: Wow, that's really interesting.  Thanks a lot for the unique response!

Answer (score 1):

```
$params = $this->params;
$data = array_filter($data, function($item) use ($params){

});
```